# writing foo with nested structs

Tags: solidity, struct

I am writing a function that adds an element to a list of structs, where each element has a nested struct inside. I know it is NOT the most efficient way to do so, but enough for a PoC. In any case, my code consists of:

```
external[] mylist;

struct external {
  string id;
  string name1:
  internal[] internalList;
};

struct internal {
  string name2;
  uint256 ammount;
}

function addElement(string memory _id,
                    string memory _name1,
                    string memory _name2,
                    uint256 _ammount ) public restricted{
   internal memory intl = internal(_name2, _ammount);
   myList.push(external(_id, _name1, intl);
}
```

You can forget about the restricted modifier;

The error I am getting here is on the 'intl' struct and it says:

> Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit
> conversion from struct Contract_Name.internal memory to struct
> Contract_Name.internal memory[] memory requested.

So I assume it is pretty obvious, but I have no clue of how to fix it and make it work. Please help

Answer (score 0):

seems like creating a mapping for an Internal struct will be better inside your External struct. Something like

```
 struct External {
  string id;
  string name1:
  mapping (uint => Internal) internals;
};
```

maybe be this will help,to understand struct, check out this [example](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html?highlight=struct#structs)